# Using OpenElement to open an Attachment with a URL

Tags: url, lotusscript

Trying to open an attachment with this url and it doesn't work. Any idea why?

https://Blah-apps.com/Development/StrongB.nsf/0/(Attach)/0/B3B9D4480BEF667C852588310078E1AE/$File/golf.pdf!%20&OpenElement

Thanks for any ideas

The attachment was originally created on the web and was an embedded object. I then wrote code to move it to a Rich Text Field and that didn't help. The error I get is
HTTP Web Server: Couldn't find design note

Answer (score 1):

This is from a note that I pulled together for HCL some time ago listing the issues we had with Domino 11 having upgraded from 9. This might help although it is not clear what version you are on.

Broken Download links for LZ1 compressed attachments. - CS0313452
After upgrading to FP5 customers found that they could not download some attachments.
We were able to reproduce this issue 100% and provided HCL with a database.
https://eon.focul.net/eon/apps/moc.nsf/xp_f_mod.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=67BC79B86B06BAFD802582B30042ACFB FoCul determined that this happens to attachments that are automatically compressed with LZ1 even when the database settings do not enable compression.

+SPR# GRHEBVYNW7 - Server - DAOS - Fixed an issue where after upgrading to 11.x,
running dbmt -c on DAOS enabled databases results in duplicate DAOS objects being stored.
This regression was introduced in 11.0.

The URL syntax affected is the old style https://<>//<>/<database.nsf>>/<>/$FILE/<>.jpg
whereas the newer “XPage”style syntax works fine
We modified our applications to use the XPages style syntax as a good work around.

This is the XPages url style

https://acme.focul.net/apps/moc.nsf/xp_f_mod.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=67BC79B86B06BAFD802582B30042ACFB

Answer (score 0):

Your use of /0/(Attach)/0 looks wrong. Try this format instead: http://host/Database/View/Document/$File/Filename?OpenElement (source: https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_ABOUT_URL_COMMANDS_FOR_OPENING_IMAGE_FILES_ATTACHMENTS_AND_OLE_OBJECTS.html)

So in your case:
https://blah-apps.com/Development/StrongB.nsf/0/B3B9D4480BEF667C852588310078E1AE/$File/golf.pdf?OpenElement

Comment: I changed the url and now get this error message. HTTP Web Server: Item Not Found Exception. I believe it can't find the document without the view listed. It appears to me that in the previous url it can't find the attachment in the document for some reason.

Comment: The 0 for view means it ignores the view and uses the UNID of the document directly. The view is not needed if you have the UNID. To me it sounds like the attachment is not in the $File field. Have you verified that?